# Retrieving query results with getResultList() taking too long

Tags: java, list, entitymanager

I have a query in the following form

```
Query query = getEm().createNativeQuery("SELECT i.claimid, i.attachmentfilename, i.invoiceid, i.invoicedate, i.invoicenumber, "
                + "i.invoicetypeid, i.dealerinvoicenumber, i.bdxid, i.capturedate, i.paid, i.paymentdate "
                + "FROM invoice i WHERE i.claimid = "+claimId
                        + " AND i.invoicetypeid = 2 order by i.invoicedate DESC LIMIT 1", Invoice.class);
        logger.info(claimId+"=starting..");
        List<Invoice> invoices = query.getResultList();
        logger.info(claimId+"=ending..");
```

The issue is once it prints "starting..", it's hanging for as long as 10min, only to pull 1 or 2 results. How can 1 or 2 records take so long?

There is a one-to-one relationship between Invoice and Claim, but it's only defined from Invoice.

Can anyone explain why that line takes so long?

Comment: What all index are associated with invoice table? How many rows are there in this table?

Comment: what happens when you execute the query through SQL management studio ? does it still take time ?

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: @Stavm - when I execute the query in psql or pg_admin, it runs very fast, 22milliseconds

Comment: @niceman - am using postgresql DB

Comment: @ngonidzashe if it works fast when you execute your query on the server, and works slow from your end point, this probably means you have a network issue. to make sure can you start a new project, that has no logic in it, but the query, see if it goes fast or not.

Comment: @SMA - there is only 1 index invoice_pkey - primary key

Comment: @Stavn -  but the database is on localhost, there is not network involment.

Comment: that's good, keep isolating, I would still start with a blank project, that only executes the query, and start comparing see where it fails.

Comment: The number of claims is 227, a claim might have 0,1 or 2 invoices at most, the problem arises when we have more than 0 claims on invoice, thats the only time when query.getResultList() hangs for too long. Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes but you said the query works very fast when run directly, i could be wrong but i'm not sure it's the data or its layout that should concern you.

Comment: how about the database driver (jar) is it latest?